# Communicator API On IIS

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I have the following error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {8885370D-B33E-44B7-875D-28E403CF9270} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

when trying to use office communicator api in iis.

This api (com) successfully works on Visual Studio. After running this web application on iis, 
I change `platform target` to `x86` and enable **32bit** application in iis app pool.

Any idea what's the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered that error when Visual Studio and Communicator were not both running under Administrator privileges.